# Do you know why the close button and close icon are not appering in large scren sizes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the code below that has a link to show a modal. But there is one issue if the screen size is small the close button in the modal footer and close icon in the modal header appears. But in large sizes dont appear.

Do you know why?

If instead of using button is used link like:                                         `<a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>`
 it works the close icon appears correctly.

Html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary test text-white" data-regid="1"> <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Test</h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              test

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/trsshs2k/

Comment: I'm not getting that problem in chrome or firefox.

Comment: Thanks, in the fiddle is also working. Do you know how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap use Icons called Glyphicons. You are using font awesome icon `fa-plus`. Use a font of Glyphicons or import font-awesome in your style.